# Add a tabstrip in Kendo

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to add a Item into a Tabstrip but I don't know how to do it, I have seen a c# code but I need to do it in Visual Basic
I tried:

```
@Code
        Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
                        .Name("TabStrip2") _
                        .Items(Function(tabstrip) tabstrip.Add().Text("tab text") _
                            .Selected(True) _
                            .Content(Sub()@<text>html content</text>
                                         End Sub),
                                                    tabStrip.Add().Text("tab text") _
                                                    .Selected(True) _
                                                    .Content(Sub()@<text>html content</text>
                                                             End Sub) _
        .Render()
    End Code
```

The c# code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("tabstrip")
          .Animation(animation => 
              animation.Open(effect => 
                  effect.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
          .Items(tabstrip =>
          {
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Paris")
                  .Selected(true)
                  .Content(@<text>
                    <div class="weather">
                        <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                        <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
                    </div>
                    <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
                  </text>);

              tabstrip.Add().Text("New York")
                  .Content(@<text>
                    <div class="weather">
                        <h2>29<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                        <p>Sunny weather in New York.</p>
                    </div>
                    <span class="sunny">&nbsp;</span>
                  </text>);

          })
```

How is the equivalent code of this c# code to visual basic code?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
@Code
        Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
            .Name("TabStrip2") _
            .Items(Function(tabstrip) tabstrip.Add().Text("TAB1") _
                .Selected(True) _
                .Content(Sub()@<text>html content</text>
                             End Sub)) _
               .Items(Function(tabstrip) tabstrip.Add().Text("TAB2") _
                   .Selected(False) _
                   .Content(Sub()@<text>html content</text>
                            End Sub)) _
            .Render()
    End Code
```